# Trying to populate a tableview however label content does not show up in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am currently working on an app that needs to load label content into a table view controller. I have created an array of string values that I want to populate the table view but for some reason the content is not showing up in the simulator. I am not getting any errors but the data does not seem to register. Any thoughts on how I can resolve this?

Below is my table view controller file:

```
 categoryTableViewController.swift
//  Style Guide
//
//  Created by Claudia Laurie on 5/30/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Claudia Laurie. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

//struct Color {
//    let red, green, blue: Double
//    init(red: Double, green: Double, blue: Double) {
//        self.red   = red
//        self.green = green
//        self.blue  = blue
//    }
//    init(white: Double) {
//        red   = white
//        green = white
//        blue  = white
//    }
//}
I

class clothing_category: NSObject {
    let name: String!
    init (name: String) {
       self.name = name
    }
}

class categoryTableViewController: UITableViewController {

// MARK: Properties 

    // Create an array to hold the clothing.
    var clothing_categories = [clothing_category]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Register cells? let me google...is this why nothing was showing up in the cells themselves despite loading the data? maybe

        self.tableView.registerClass(catgeoriesTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "categoriesTableViewCell")



        // Load sample data
        loadSampleClothing_categories()
    }
        func loadSampleClothing_categories() {
            clothing_categories.append(clothing_category(name:"Jackets"))
            clothing_categories.append(clothing_category(name: "Accessories"))
            clothing_categories.append(clothing_category(name: "Pants"))
            clothing_categories.append(clothing_category(name: "Color"))
            clothing_categories.append(clothing_category(name: "Tops"))
            clothing_categories.append(clothing_category(name: "Dressing for an Occaision"))



        // Load up the array when the view is loaded.

        clothing_categories.append(clothing_category(name:"Jackets"))
        clothing_categories.append(clothing_category(name: "Accessories"))
        clothing_categories.append(clothing_category(name: "Pants"))
        clothing_categories.append(clothing_category(name: "Color"))
        clothing_categories.append(clothing_category(name: "Tops"))
        clothing_categories.append(clothing_category(name: "Dressing for an Occaision"))

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return clothing_categories.count
    }

    // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
    let cellIdentifier = "categoriesTableViewCell"


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // This is the line that is failing, lets find out why
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("categoriesTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! catgeoriesTableViewCell
       //Fetches the appropriate clothing_catgeory for the data source layout.
        let category = clothing_categories[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameclothing_category.text = category.name
        return cell

    }
```

I believe I have also properly created an outlet connection to the datasource and delegate.

Comment: Why do you expect your data to appear in Interface Builder? It will only appear in your running app.

Comment: It also does not show up in the app simulator :/

Comment: What does the debugger show you when you use it? Are the correct methods being called? Are the correct values being returned in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? Have you checked your `cellIdentifier` is correct in both IB and your code? Basically what problems have you ruled out in your debugging?

Answer (score 1):

```
self.tableView.registerClass(catgeoriesTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "categoriesTableViewCell")
```

This line is causing problem for you.

If you are loading the cell from a nib or xib then you first need to load the nib and then register it. The nibname has to match the file name and restoration id.

[image: Restoration]

```
let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "LanguagePickerCellView", bundle: nil)
tableView.registerNib(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
```

If you are using prototype cells directly in interface builder then you just have to put the reuseIdentifier in storyboard.

[image: ReuseIdentifier]

If you are using a **UITableViewController** directly then you don't need to link dataSource and delegate, it's done automatically. If you are using plain TableView then you have to link dataSource and delegate.